# How to generate client side code with NSwag for web sockets

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, code-generation, nswag

I'm currently working on a .net core application, we generate the client side code (angular 8 / typescript) with NSwag. We also have a websocket (SignalR). The Angular client app listen for events on the websocket.
The websocket events are not present in the REST API (absent from swagger.json) and not present in the generated client code.

How could I tell Nswag to also generate the websocket events ?

I'm using the latest NSwag version, with asp.net core 2.2.

Comment: See https://github.com/RicoSuter/SigSpec/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I am just now having the same question. We are in this together.